# xrandr always has a VGA-1 or VGA-2 without physical display

Tags: 14.04, 13.10

I upgraded to 13.10 and since then have issues with my display detection on my Thinkpad E530. xrandr always finds a VGA-1 or VGA-2 display and activates it without there being a physical device connected. This always creates problems for my window managers, because they sometimes try to show stuff on the second display which doesn't really exit. The lazy solution of just deactiving VGA-1 via `xrandr --output VGA-1 --off` resulted in now there being a VGA-2, so I think this is not the way to go. What could be the real issue here? What to do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a Thinkpad 530 to double-check, but it looks like your mainboard sees a phantom VGA where there is none.

Look in **/sys/class/drm** for a list of video outputs of the E530.

There should be one labelled as **card0-VGA-1**. Remove the **card0-**, that's the name of the output in question.

The fix should be to edit **/etc/default/grub**, you have to add **video=VGA-1:d** between the quotes in the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX line (the 12th line).

So, if your video output was **VGA-1**, change
**GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""** to
**GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=VGA-1:d"**

After you finish editing, don't forget to run **update-grub**.

Comment: The laptop comes with two graphics card. One onboard intel and a second card from NVidia. If I understand correctly I don't really wnat to deactivate on boot, or do I? I thought the intel is used for Gnome and the nvidia gets used for games. But I really don't know enough about that topic to be sure or look it up.

Comment: Btw. for whatever reason the bounty had a timeout. If I implement your solution I will of course add the bounty back before I mark your answer as solution. ;)

Comment: I have a similar setup - a DELL E6530 with Intel + Nvidia. This stuff with two graphics cards is trial-and-error in most cases since you never know what influences what.

However, the **video=VGA-1:d** part disables the *output*, not the *card*. Your **/sys/class/drm** output is hierarchic - you have **card0-VGA-1** meaning level 1: card0, level 2: VGA-1 as its *output*. Could be several other **card0-[XXX]** as well in addition. You just disable the output of the phantom device.

Comment: That explains a lot. I'll try it!

Comment: Can't add the 50 karma bounty back. Could only add a 100 karma bounty, which would cost all I have. :-/